# Extracting data of an Element via JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to extract data from one div class, but it is showing the whole string where I want to get data items one by one.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(get_html);
String Title = doc.getElementsByClass("jTit").text();
String CoName = doc.getElementsByClass("coName").text();
System.out.println(Title);
System.out.println(CoName);
```

Comment: What do you mean by data? Could you please add an example XML and an expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have more than one element with the specified class, the [getElementsByClass](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByClass%28java.lang.String%29) returns a collection containing all those [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html). So you probably want to extract the text of each one, for that  you need to iterate over this collection the get each element and then get the text from it.

Here is an example

```
public class JsoupTest {
    @Test
    public void getTextByClass() {
        String html = "<html>\r\n" + 
                "    <body>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"jTit\">jtit 1</div>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"coName\">coname 1</div>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"foo\">foo</div>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"coName\">coname 2</div>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"jTit\">jtit 2</div>\r\n" + 
                "        <div class=\"bar\">bar</div>\r\n" + 
                "    </body>\r\n" + 
                "</html>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements jTitElements = doc.getElementsByClass("jTit");
        for(Element e : jTitElements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }

        Elements coNameElements = doc.getElementsByClass("coName");
        for(Element e : coNameElements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
jtit 1
jtit 2
coname 1
coname 2
```